# Resources in magnetized accretion disk

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, magnetohydrodynamics, accretion-disk

I'm looking for some resources in magnetized accretion disk. Preferably a book or an article review that starts with un-magnetized accretion disk theory.

While I have some familiarity with accretion disk theory (I'm familiar with the Shakura Sunyaev model), I would prefer to reaffirm mi ground in HD models before moving to MHD models.

Comment: There is a rather detailed and useful article by Paul Bellan in the _Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society_ journal, doi:[10.1093/mnras/stw562](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/458/4/4400/2613843).  To get the unmagnetized version, just take the limit as $\mathbf{B} \rightarrow 0$.